# How to get the data of selected row in ag grid in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have setup ag-grid in angular2 which works fine but i am not able to get the value of selected row...There are no errors in my console window...This is how i am initialising the grid...

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
selector: 'aggride',
template: `

<div class="tr-card" >
<ag-grid-ng2  #agGrid of mgrid   class="ag-fresh"   rowHeight="40px"    
               [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
                [rowData] = "rowData"
     enableCellExpressions="true"  
 enableSorting="true"  
  unSortIcon="true"
rowSelection="single"
(getSelectedRows) = "getSelectedRows()"
(onSelectionChanged) = "onSelectionChanged()"
>
</ag-grid-ng2>
</div>
`,
directives: [(<any>window).ag.grid.AgGridNg2],
})
```

And this my code inside the class to get the selected value

```
export class AgGride {
gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: 'columnDefs',
    rowData: 'rowData',
    rowSelection: 'single',
    getSelectedRows: 'getSelectedRows',
    onSelectionChanged: 'onSelectionChanged'
};

columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Make", field: "make", editable: true },
    { headerName: "Model", field: "model", editable: true },
    { headerName: "Color", field: "Color", editable: true }
];

rowData = [
    { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", Color: "Red"},
    { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", Color: "Blue"},
    { make: "Tata", model: "X100", Color: "Blue"},
    { make: "Volvo", model: "X5", Color: "White"},      
];

mgrid: any;
onSelectionChanged() {
    var selectedRows = this.mgrid.ag.this.gridOptions.getSelectedRows();
    console.log(selectedRows);


}
}
```

Somebody please tell me how can i correct my mistake so that i will get the data/value of selected row in my console window...

Comment: Try this method:  https://softans.com/question/how-to-get-the-data-of-selected-row-in-ag-grid-in-angular2/#comment-488

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On template, e.g.:

```
(rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)'
(cellClicked)='onCellClicked($event)'
(selectionChanged) = 'onSelectionChanged($event)'
```

and then on component class:

```
onRowClicked(event: any) { console.log('row', event); }
onCellClicked(event: any) { console.log('cell', event); }
onSelectionChanged(event: any) { console.log("selection", event); }
```

Use Chrome console to check the event object contents.

Comment: If you had use had used the chrome console to check the event object contents, you would've seen that onSelectionChanged does not contain information about selected nodes.

Answer (score 9):

you can use api.getSelectedRows() that Returns a array of selected rows data.

```
 public getSelectedRows(){
        let rowsSelection = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
        console.info(rowsSelection);
      }
```

that's work for me.

Answer (score 3):

On your HTML bind `rowClicked` event to your own function as follows.

```
 <ag-grid-angular #grid
      style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="rowList" [columnDefs]="columnsList" [rowSelection]="selectionMode"
      (rowClicked)="onRowClick($event)"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

then on your TS or in your JS use the api as follows

```
onRowClick(event) {
    if (this.selectionMode === 'multiple') {
      this.selectedEntity = this.grid.api.getSelectedRows();
    } else {
      this.selectedEntity = this.grid.api.getSelectedRows()[0];
    }
}
```

When your grid has a feature like multiple selections all the selected data won't pass with the `event` parameter. It will always be the selected row only.

Reason I didn't encourage the `selectionChanged` event was, It will always call the `rowClicked` event before `selectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `onSelectionChanged()` you can get selected data from the `onSelectionChanged` function by using `api.getSelectedRows()`.

```
selectedRow: any;
canceLDateAGGrid() {
    this.dateGridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [{
            headerName: this.Label[0].GEN_ORG_lblName,
            field: 'DependantName',
            width: 200,
            filter: 'agTextColumnFilter'
        }, ],
        showRowSelection: true,
        checkboxSelection: false,
        onSelectionChanged: (event) = > this.onSelectionChanged(event),
    };
}
onSelectionChanged(event) {
    let selectdata = event.api.getSelectedNodes();
    this.selectedRow = event.api.getSelectedRows();
    console.log(this.selectedRow)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, row selection must be enabled by setting `gridOptions.rowSelection` to either `"single"` or `"mulitple"`, depending on the selection behavior you'd like to implement.

You can then use the grid API method `getSelectedNodes()` to return a list of all currently selected rows in ag-Grid. Extracting the data from each node is as simple as mapping over each node and returning its data property.

Here is the code when using a JavaScript framework:

```
getSelectedRowData() {
    let selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();
    let selectedData = selectedNodes.map(node => node.data);
    alert(`Selected Nodes:\n${JSON.stringify(selectedData)}`);
    return selectedData;
}
```

You can also see this illustrated in the Angular/React/Vue.js examples below:

[Angular](https://plnkr.co/edit/V4C6TwBvOUTMWtrL)

[React](https://plnkr.co/edit/WPy4PgYBvzHSWZDa?preview)

[Vue.js](https://plnkr.co/edit/srqDYmHjFTmiA2jg?preview)

[Vanilla JS](https://plnkr.co/edit/w7uPmlRYROTnyU7E?preview)
*Note: When using Vanilla JS, the gridApi and columnApi can be reached from the gridOptions Object.*

Read the full post on our [blog](https://blog.ag-grid.com/how-to-get-the-data-of-selected-rows-in-ag-grid/) or check out our [documentation](https://ag-grid.com//documentation-main/documentation.php?_ga=2.229567964.1768000711.1587912375-573717243.1579772770) for a great variety of scenarios you can implement with ag-Grid.

Ahmed Gadir | Developer @ ag-Grid

Answer (score 0):

```
onRowSelected: params => {
  const selectedRows = params.api.getSelectedRows();
  console.log(selectedRows);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { parseI18nMeta } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/view/i18n/meta';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { ColDef, GridReadyEvent, ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { MyCellComponent, MyCellParams } from './my-cell/my-cell.component';
    import { OverComponent } from './over/over.component';
    import { RemoveButtonComponent } from './remove-button/remove-button.component';
    import { UnderComponent } from './under/under.component';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
        {
          field: 'athlete',
          cellRenderer: MyCellComponent,
          cellRendererParams: {
            buttonText: 'Name',
          } as MyCellParams
        },
        {
          field: 'age',
          cellRendererSelector: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
            if (params.value < 25) {
              return { component: UnderComponent, params: {} };
            }
            return { component: OverComponent }
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'country',
          cellRenderer: (params: ICellRendererParams) => {
            return `<b> !! ${params.value} </b>`
          }
        },
        { field: 'year' },
        { field: 'sport' },
        { field: 'gold' },
        { field: 'silver' },
        { field: 'bronze' },
        { field: 'total' },
        {
          field: 'action',
          cellRenderer: RemoveButtonComponent,
          cellRendererParams: { context: this },
        },
      ];
      public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
      };
    
      public rowData$!: Observable<any[]>;
      gridApi: any;
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
      onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.rowData$ = this.http
          .get<any[]>('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json');
        //params.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns()
      }
      onRemoveClick(data: any) {
        console.log(data, "data")
      }
      onClick() {
        alert("hi")
      }
    }

**//Remove Component**

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-remove-button',
  template: `<button (click)="clickHandler(rowData)">Remove</button>`,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class RemoveButtonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  public rowData: any;
  private params: any;

  public agInit(params: { data: any, context: any }) {
    this.rowData= params.data;
    this.params = params;
  };

  public clickHandler(data: any) {
    this.params.context.onRemoveClick(data);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```