# How to find out the index of a selected row of a ag-grid

Tags: angular, indexing, ag-grid-angular

I have stuck in one problem, i want to add new row to the ag grid for specified row(i.e i just want to add a new row just below the selected row in a ag grid)

As a first step i am trying to get the index number of a selected row.
But unable to get the index of a selected row.

Below is the code that i have tried to print index in ag grid.

In columnDefs:

```
public columnDefs = [
      {headerName: 'index', valueGetter: (args) => this._getIndexValue(args), field: 'index',editable: true, width:100}]

 _getIndexValue(args: ValueGetterParams): any {
     return args.node.rowIndex;
  }
```

But this code working as expected and i am able to see the index column in ag grid.But how do i get the index for particular selected row?

I am using below code to get the selected row.

```
this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
```

But no where i am getting the index of that row.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the data of selected row in ag grid in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292580/how-to-get-the-data-of-selected-row-in-ag-grid-in-angular2)

Comment: I am able to get the data of the selected Row using gridApi.getSelectedRows() method but i am unable to find out the index there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the answer I [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292580/how-to-get-the-data-of-selected-row-in-ag-grid-in-angular2), you can use `(rowClicked)="onRowClick($event)"` on the `ag-grid-angular` element and in your `.ts` have:

```js
onRowClick(event: any): void {
    console.log(event.rowIndex);
}
```

Check [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-iuhmns).

Answer (score 1):

Use below:

```
gridApi.getSelectedNodes()
```

As per the below documentation

> **[getSelectedRows](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/#reference-selection-getSelectedRows)** - Returns a list of selected rows (i.e. row data that you provided).

> **[getSelectedNodes](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/#reference-selection-getSelectedNodes)** - Returns a list of selected nodes. Getting the
> underlying node (rather than the data) is useful when working with
> tree / aggregated data, as the node can be traversed.

Answer (score 0):

Using ag-grid JS, below method works fine for me to get the row index. Sharing here so that it might be needful to someone in some cases.

```
var rowIndex = $($(this).closest('.ag-row')[0]).attr('row-index');
```